# Will and would difference

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

> 1) Having faster computers would make for a more efficient system.
>
> 2) Having faster computers will make for a more efficient system

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Does the first question means that if we had computers (we don't have them now), it would make for a more efficient system?
And does the second sentence mean that we have computers and they are going to make our system more efficient?

Comment: It's a matter of tentative vs more assured, respectively

Answer (score 1):

I interpret it as :

1 - A hypothetical. If we **were** to have faster computers, then they **would** make the system more efficient

2 - More certain. We **are** going to have faster computers and they **will** make the system more efficient

Having said that, they are very similar, and even #2 doesn't mean that it's 100% certain. But #1 is always hypothetical.

It's not really about if we have the computers currently (future vs present). It's more about the certainty/likelihood of getting the computers in the future.