# Will vs would in the following question

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, modal-verbs, will-would

What's the difference between:

"I would go on a walk with my friend tonight. "

"I will go on a walk with my friend tonight. "

Comment: "I _would_ go on a walk with my friend tonight, but I don't think my injured ankle is strong enough yet."

Comment: Have you looked up the difference between *will* and *would?*

Comment: Lots of dupes: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/232969/will-and-would-difference?rq=1 https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/236265/will-and-would-usage-differences?rq=1 https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252668/will-and-would-modal-verb-differences?rq=1 https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/281080/would-be-vs-will-be?rq=1

Comment: What @KateBunting said. *I **would** do it* normally refers to a *counterfactual* [future] action - so it's often followed by a ***but-*** clause explaining *why I'm not **actually** going to do it.* Note that *would* here (as the past tense of ***will***) strongly implies ***willingness / volition / intention*** (as in *I **want** to do it, but I **can't***).

Answer (score 0):

"I would go on a walk with my friend tonight." Would is the past of will and we often select past forms of modals verbs to talk about unreal situations in the present or future. This sentence doesn't make a lot of sense on it own.

"I will go on a walk with my friend tonight." Will expresses willingness or volition or 'future as fact' or prediction but again, on its own, we lose nuance.